# How to set external workbook data as a chart's data source?

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I'm trying to use external workbook's data and show it at the chart.
I tried like this:

```
    Workbook externalWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(@"..\SomeFolder\ExternalWorkbook.xls");
    Sheet extSheet = externalWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);

    Chart chart = drawing.CreateChart(anchor);
    LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory.CreateLineChartData();

    ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom);
    ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateValueAxis(AxisPosition.Left);

    ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(extSheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
    ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(extSheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

    var s1 = data.AddSeries(xs, ys1);
    s1.SetTitle(serie1);

    chart.Plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
```

But it doesn't working properly, so at the end, at Excel file in the chart property I have something like: 
 
[image]
 
Instead of:

 
[image] 
 
And obviously it doesn't working normally.
So how do you think, what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I should use some specific function in such case?
Is it even possible to use data from external workbook at the chart with poi apache?

Comment: Why not just bring the data into the sheet with the chart then plot from there? A link will get updated so that is not an issue.

Comment: @SolarMike thank you for the comment, I also thought about that, but, unfortunately it's a specific of my task, I have to take data from external workbook and can't change current workbook with chart. Only show data there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508297/why-cant-i-link-one-workbook-to-another-in-apache-poi/46513213#46513213. Note my last edit.