# Receiving "Book not linked" when evaluating formular which references another workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have two woorkbooks:

1. map.xlsx
2. req.xlsx

map.xlsx has a sheet *Mapping*, req.xlsx has a sheet *ABC Request*.

I want to insert and evaluate a formula in map.xlsx which references req.xlsx. According to [POI Documentation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html) I use the following code.

```
FormulaEvaluator mapWbEvaluator = mapWb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
FormulaEvaluator reqWbEvaluator = reqWb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

Map<String, FormulaEvaluator> evalMap = new HashMap<>();
evalMap.put("map.xlsx", mapWbEvaluator);
evalMap.put("req.xlsx", reqWbEvaluator);

mapWbEvaluator.setupReferencedWorkbooks(evalMap);

Sheet mapSheet = mapWb.getSheet("Mapping");

CellReference tgtRef = new CellReference("A25");
Cell tgtCell = mapSheet.getRow(tgtRef.getRow()).getCell(tgtRef.getCol());
tgtCell.setCellFormula("IF('[req.xlsx]ABC Request'!R28,1,2)");
CellValue cellVal = mapWbEvaluator.evaluate(tgtCell);
```

When the last line is executed I receive the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Book not linked
> for filename req.xlsx     at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFEvaluationWorkbook.resolveBookIndex(BaseXSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:135)

Any idea what's going wrong? Do I miss anything?

Comment: Does your spreadsheet already contain a formula that references the other workbook? Or are you trying to set a new formula then evaluate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormulaEvaluator.setupReferencedWorkbooks` only tells the evaluator where the linked workbooks are. It does **not** link them. They must be linked already in the main workbook (the workbook where main evaluator `mapWbEvaluator` comes from).

Also `tgtCell.setCellFormula("IF('[req.xlsx]ABC Request'!R28,1,2)");` will not link the workbook. It only sets that formula into the cell. But the `req.xlsx` would must be linked within the `map.xlsx` using a external links table. In that external links table the link gets an index, `1` for example, and the internally stored formula then would be `IF('[1]ABC Request'!R28,1,2)`. There the `1` points to the external links table which links to the `req.xlsx` then.

`Apache poi` does not provide creating or changing external links table. There is [ExternalLinksTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/ExternalLinksTable.html) but that only gets read while creating the `apache poi` `XSSFWorkbook`. There is nothing to create a new external links table for the workbook. And `ExternalLinksTable` does not provide methods to add new external links.

In [Why can't I link one workbook to another in Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508297/why-cant-i-link-one-workbook-to-another-in-apache-poi/46513213#46513213) I have shown an example for using low level methods to create an external links table to link two `*.xlsx` workbooks together. In that case to get chart data from a linked workbook. But the problem is the same for to get cell data from a linked workbook.

So either you will bothering yourself with that code and understand what needs to be done to create external links between two workbooks or you will wait until `apache poi` provides that feature in it's high level classes.

Comment: Sadly it needs a volunteer to contribute the code, or someone to sponsor the development, both of which have been lacking for multi-workbook formulas for some time :(